# Status report: Twitter module using unautheticated api

Tags: social-network

So, I'm getting kind of a strange error in my status report about my twitter module. I get an error that the twitter pull authentication is using an unauthorized api" Below that it says that the Twitter modules doesn't have any authorized accounts, and that I should add an authorized account via the accounts page. The issue is that I have authorized accounts attached.

I'm using twitter module 6.2 and twitter pull version 7-2.0alpha3.

callback url is: twitter/oauth
the host is : twitter.com 
and the api is: https://api.twitter.com

Not sure if this an incompatibility between versions, or what the problem is here. How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter module was misconfigured, not updated.